# How to make a Loop in VBA that do an operation of Sumproduct when a condition is met

Tags: vba, for-loop, sumproduct

I want to do a loop that does a SumProduct operation by each group identified with Id. I mean I need an operation SumProduct between column 2 and 3, and that the result appears in the empty cell of that column. I have tried with the next code but It's not working that I expect. I have tried of changing the Starpoint in the range but my solutions have not worked. Thanks for the feedback and help you can give me.

```
Startrow = 2
Lastpoint = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
For i = Startrow To Lastpoint + 1
If Cells(i, 3).Value = "" Then Cells(i, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(a, b)
a = Range("C2: C" & Cells(i, 3).End(xlDown).Row)
b = Range("B2: B" & Cells(i, 3).End(xlDown).Row)
Next i
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub testAgain2GroupID()

  Dim i As Long, im1 As Long, startRow As Long, lastPoint As Long

  Dim a As Range, b As Range

  startRow = 2
  lastPoint = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

  Do While (startRow < lastPoint)

    '
    ' check id cell for group of identical id:
    '
    For i = startRow To lastPoint
      If (Cells(i, 1).Value = "") Then
        Exit For
      End If
    Next

    '
    ' now we found the group:
    '
    im1 = i - 1
    Set a = Range("C" & startRow & ":C" & im1)
    Set b = Range("B" & startRow & ":B" & im1)

    '
    ' so sumprod():
    '
    Cells(i, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(a, b)

    '
    ' prepare for next loop:
    '

    startRow = i + 1

  Loop

End Sub
```

I tested it and it worked for me.

You can run this code again and again without changing result as the empty cell in id column will never be filled.

[image: this is a screen capture]

Comment: Thanks @jacouh, it worked perfectly. Could you recommend me a book or material to study this?

Comment: You could start with https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/ . You could test their sample codes for training.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually define the ranges `a,b` in the code. Try this.

```
Option Explicit 'pay attention and read up on this. crucial to developing bug free code.

Sub test()

Dim startRow as Long, lastPoint as Long 'always, always declare variables and the type

startRow = 2
lastpoint = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = Startrow To Lastpoint + 1

    Dim a as Range, b as Range
    Set a = Range("C2: C" & Cells(i, 3).End(xlDown).Row)
    Set b = Range("B2: B" & Cells(i, 3).End(xlDown).Row)

   If Cells(i, 3).Value = "" Then 
      Cells(i, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(a, b)
   End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but that code doesn't do what I expect. It produces the same results than before. What I need is that the SumProduct operation be calculated per each Id. I mean B2:B7 and C2:C7 and the result be shown in the cell C8. The same for Id 2 and 5.